# WS Service Binary response to PDF

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rest, pdf

I have a WS that returns a binary response.

What i need is when i request the service through ajax request, getting the response and generate again the original pdf.

However i can generate the pdf, but i don't know why i'm not getting the pdf content.

```
    $.ajax({
          url: resource_str,
          type: "GET",
          async:   true,
        },
          success: function(data) {
        var file = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'});
                        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        window.open(fileURL);
                        var a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.href = fileURL;
                        a.download = "Testing.pdf";
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                        $(window).on('focus', function(e) {
                          $('a').remove();
                        });
        },fails: function (data){
          console.log('Error');
        }
    })
```

what am i doing wrong? 
Why i'm losing the content?

i'm debating with this question for a while.
Everything i need is to stream the pdf as binary from the WS and next be able to generate the pdf again using jquery.

Comment: Could you include your ajax request too, please?

Comment: Try this approach: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qjrbzv

Comment: @Hackerman that approach works well! I've already tested. What i need is to do the same in jquery! This request will be used to receive Json!

Comment: the problem is, and based on my research, that jquery $.ajax, doesn't handle binary data in a good way...that is why the vanilla approach is recommended on this sort of tasks.

Comment: @Hackerman i would like to do the approach without other js frameworks, if possible!

Comment: that approach use just plain javascript....there is no other framework involved :)

Comment: Do you know how to do it with vanilla approach? Could you help me

Comment: This piece of code uses just plain javascript: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qjrbzv

Comment: @Hackerman i already tested that piece of code! But in this way i can't handle a json object! And I need to be able to handle json objects, because the WS response will be one!